# Adding FutureBuilder to ListView children property

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am currently reading some data from a textfile (async function) and displaying it using a ListView.

```
void readData() async {
  final file = await localFile;
  String body = await file.readAsString();
  if(body.isNotEmpty)
    ListData.tiles.addToStoredList(body);
}
```

Since this is an async function, I decided to use FutureBuilder to get the list and display it

```
ListView(
    children : FutureBuilder <List<Widget>> ...
)
```

doesn't seem to work. What is the alternative to display a list of widgets under a list view when I get data from an async function.

Comment: so you need a `FutureBuilder` that builds a `ListView` in its `builder` property -you get  the data from `snapshot` parameter

Comment: Correct, I am a beginner to flutter, can you give me a code snippet?

Comment: there is an example in `FutureBuilder` official documentation - but better option is to ask google for `flutter futurebuilder` - it will find dozens of tutorials on it

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
​
final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);
​
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
​
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
​
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
​
        return ListView(
          children: [
            Container(height: 150, color: Colors.red),
            Container(height: 150, color: Colors.yellow),
            Container(height: 150, color: Colors.blue),
            Container(height: 150, color: Colors.orange),
            Container(height: 150, color: Colors.red),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No, so what I want is to have children under the ListView() which is returned by the FutureBuilder

Comment: For example,
ListView(
    children : FutureBuilder <List<Widget>> {....}
)